# Entity field array type in forms

Tags: symfony

I have an entity

```
class Icon
{
...

     /**
     * @var array $padding
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="padding", type="array")
     */
    private $padding;

    /**
     * Set padding
     *
     * @param array $padding
     * @return Icon
     */
    public function setPadding($padding)
    {
        $this->padding = $padding;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get padding
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getPadding()
    {
        return $this->padding;
    }

...
}
```

, an icon form

```
<?php

namespace Acme\ExBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class IconPaddingType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('padding', new PaddingType())
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Acme\ExBundle\Entity\Icon'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'icontype';
    }
}
```

and a padding form

```
<?php

namespace Acme\ExBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class PaddingType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('top', 'integer', array('data' => 0))
            ->add('right', 'integer', array('data' => 0))
            ->add('bottom', 'integer', array('data' => 0))
            ->add('left', 'integer', array('data' => 0))
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'paddingtype';
    }
}
```

If I create or update icon with `IconType`

and fill paddings, icon saves as I expect.

But after this when I edit icon again,

`PaddingForm` does not use `icon.padding` values

to populate the form ( top, left, right, bottom are '0' again).

How do you fill embed `PaddingForm` with `icon.padding` values?

Comment: Post your controller code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `data` overrides the data passed when form is constructed.

I suggest setting `0` values within your entity as defaults (either in property directly or in `__construct`) and removing those `data` properties from form.

```
class IconPadding{
    ....
    public function __construct(){
        $this->left = $this->rigth = $this->bottom = $this->top = 0;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: yep you're right `$builder->add('top', 'integer', array('data' => 0))`
overwrites icon.padding values
i just remove them and set defaults in Icon Entity

`    /**
     * @var array $padding
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="padding", type="array")
     */
    private $padding = array(
        'top'    => 0,
        'right'  => 0,
        'bottom' => 0,
        'left'   => 0
        );
`